# Paypal advanced checkout integration: how to pass amount and other data to create an order?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-advanced-checkout

I'm trying to migrate the PayPal form with IPN notification to the advanced checkout using PHP and JS.
I've got many doubts. The major is this:

In PHP I've got a MyOrder example class. I report only a crucial part of the `createOrder()` method:

```
// Create order
public function createOrder()
{
    $this->generateAccessToken();
    $data = [
        "intent" => "CAPTURE",
        "purchase_units" => [[
            "amount" => [
                "currency_code" => "EUR",
                "value" => "100",
            ],
            "description" => "my product",
            "soft_descriptor" => "my prod",
        ]],
        "application_context" => [
            "shipping_preference" => "NO_SHIPPING"
        ]
    ];

    $paypal_button = [
        "payment_source" => [
            "paypal" => [
                // billing address
                "address" => [
                    "address_line_1" => "aaa",
                    "address_line_2" => "aNews",
                    "admin_area_2" => "Springfield",
                    "postal_code" => "34343",
                    "admin_area_1" => "33",
                    "country_code" => "IT"
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ];

    /* We merge the two arrays above only if the order is created through the PayPal Button */
    if (isset($_GET['task']) && $_GET['task'] == 'button') $data = array_merge($data, $paypal_button);
    $requestid = "new-order-" . date("Y-m-d-h-i-s");
    $json = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl,
        array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->accessToken,
                "PayPal-Request-Id: " . $requestid,
                "Prefer: return=representation"
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
        )
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r($response);
}
```

And I also have to app.js from the same example code. When I push the button to pay, it calls the `createOrder()` method:

```
paypal
  .Buttons({
    // When a payment button is clicked, an order is created on the server and the order ID is returned
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch('backend.php?task=button', {
        method: "post",
        // use the "body" param to optionally pass
        // additional order information like product ids or amount. 
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((order) => order.id);
    },

    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
         .....
    },
  }).render("#paypal-button-container");
```

The question is about the comment on the app.js:

```
// use the "body" param to optionally pass
// additional order information like product ids or amount.
```

I think that I need to add to the "body" param the `$data` structure that I have in PHP.
Do I have to modify the app.js and add the `$data` with a `stringify`? Or do I have to change it in PHP?

Do someone have an example where amount and description are parametrized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `body` parameter to the fetch. Its value should be a JSON.stringify() of a `cart` object or similar. Here is an example:

```js
              return fetch("/api/paypal/create-order", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  cart: [
                    {
                      sku: "1blwyeo8",
                      quantity: 2,
                    },
                    {
                      sku: "i5b1g92y",
                      quantity: 1,
                    }
                  ],
                }),
              })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((orderData) => {
                  if (orderData?.id) {
                    return orderData.id;
                  } else {
```

(from: https://github.com/paypal-examples/paypal-sdk-server-side-integration/blob/main/public/buttons.html#L51 )

The PHP will receive the JSON as a post data string, which it can then decode into a PHP array and utilize the `cart` object it receives. *(Look up a guide on how to read JSON input with PHP if you need it, because it is not `$_POST` like form data.)*

The contents of the object/array should essentially reflect the user's cart contents: a list of item IDs (`sku` i.e. stock keeping unit is the parameter name used by the PayPal v2 Orders API) and their quantities.

The backend should iterate over the cart array to calculate a total, and it can also include an amount with breakdown and `items` array which will show in the PayPal transaction details. The amount breakdown object is required if including an `items` array. See the [create order API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) for details.